# How to create a class that returns different objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I am trying to do the following:

```py
#A wrapper object that based on it's parameters returns other objects
class A():
   def __new__(cls, config):
     if config.type == "1":
       return C(config)
     elif config.type == "2":
       return D(config)
```

How do you call this pattern and how do you do it in python? `__new__` doesn't seem to accept arguments.

Comment: Please make this a rully running example showing the error.

Comment: `__new__` does accept arguments. I fleshed out a working program from your example and... well... it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__new__` does accept arguments and it can be used as a factory for other classes like your example attempts to do. From [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)

> Classes are callable. These objects normally act as factories for new
> instances of themselves, but variations are possible for class types
> that override **new**(). The arguments of the call are passed to
> **new**() and, in the typical case, to **init**() to initialize the new instance.

A working example is

```
class C:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.what = "C"
        print("i am C")

class D:
    
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.what = "D"
        print("i am D")

class A():
   def __new__(cls, config):
     if config == "1":
       return C(config)
     elif config == "2":
       return D(config)
   
foo = A("1")
print(foo.what, type(foo))
bar = A("2")
print(bar.what, type(bar))
```